# Do you have to clear Moroccan immigration at any point flying Zurich-Casablanca-(Tanger)-Gibraltar?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, airports, morocco, casablanca

I'm considering buying a ticket Zurich-Gibraltar with Royal Air Maroc in a single multi-city booking (a normal booking cannot be made on that route), and with hand luggage only. I would check in online and get both boarding passes in Zurich.

The proposed trip consists of flight AT 937 Zurich-Casablanca, and flight AT 990 Casablanca-(Tanger)-Gibraltar, with Tanger being a technical stop, where however passengers can get on and off.

AT 937 arrives at terminal 2 in Casablanca, while AT 990 leaves from terminal 1. According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=ma&SUBSECTION=TW&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines, airside transit is possible between the two.

My question is: **would I have to clear Moroccan immigration at any point during this journey, given that AT 990 has a domestic leg**?

I've already contacted Royal Air Maroc and received different answers. Some say you enter Morocco in Casablanca, get off the Gibraltar flight in Tanger, exit Morocco and re-board the flight. Others say you remain airside in Casablanca, and that those only flying the domestic leg still clear Moroccan immigration at Casablanca and Tanger due to the nature of the route.

**Which is correct?**

Comment: Can you check in online also for the second flight? Not sure you could get your boarding pass in the transit area. Also have you read the reviews of the airport?

Comment: @mts Yes, I can check in online for the Gibraltar flight. Regarding the transit area's comfort level, I really couldn't care less.

Comment: Transit area at CMN is fine. Security + passport control when leaving Morocco from the airport OTOH is a total mess, very long lines

Comment: @davidvc The question is if I need to clear passport control at Casablanca and/or Tanger for this itinerary, as I'm not allowed to enter Morocco

Comment: @Crazydre how come you are not allowed? Have you asked your consulate/embassy in Morocco about this? Last time I contacted mine they took a few days but replied in perfect detail.

Comment: @mts I no longer have a passport (just an identity card), that's why, and as I live abroad it costs a fortune to get one. Nor do I need one to travel from Switzerland to Gibraltar, so: whether I can do this trip entirely depends on whether I need to clear Moroccan immigration

Comment: I see the point. Also potentially Zurich airport may give you some insight since in the end it will be their employees to check you in or not?

Comment: Can you find out which terminals you'll use? If both are Terminal 2 then I think you'll probably be fine, you'll probably just go through the disorderly but straightforward "International Transfers" hall where you get your bags scanned and show your passport to a bored guy who's just standing by the X-ray machine who'll just glance at it and nod like "Yes, that's a passport", and the only problem will be the long queue. If it's Terminal 1, I don't know, you might need to go through Domestic Transfers, I've never used that terminal.

Comment: @user568458 Says on the airline's website that the flight from Zurich arrives at T2, while the flight to Tanger and Gibraltar leaves from Terminal 1. However, T1 is **not** domestic-only, as Iberia's nonstop flight to Madrid (sold on Royal Air Maroc's website) departs from there.

Comment: Since you're an EU citizen, why do you care?

Comment: Are you going one-way only or also back to ZRH on the same route?

Comment: @mts One way, plan to fly with easyjet to London afterwards

Comment: @JonathanReez What does my nationality have to do with it? We're talking about Morocco here

Comment: Well, you don't need a visa for Morocco.

Comment: @JonathanReez But I *do* need a *passport* to enter, that's the issue, and I no longer have one (and would have to pay a fortune to get one from my embassy). So what about airport transit, that's the question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not hold a valid travel document for Morocco I think you will be refused to board in Zurich but you should contact the airport about this matter.

Why do you not fly to Malaga (EU) and then take a two hour bus to Gibraltar? 
You can travel this route for less than 100 euro easily..
I bet this will be cheaper and faster than first flying to Morocco and then with an intermediate stop onwards to Gibraltar.

Edit:
In addition you can contact the Moroccan Embassy to see if they accept your European Identity card as there are some countries that accept them even if there is no formal agreement between those countries. For Dutch this was the case with Morocco but this is now no longer the case.

Comment: Morocco stopped accepting EU ID cards in summer 2015. That's why I'm asking if I'll have to enter Morocco as part of this itinerary. And as for the choice of route, I got a voucher with Royal Air Maroc